# google-php-api-client moving from localhost to remote

Tags: php, api, oauth, client, public-key

So I built a website that uses [google-api-php-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) to grab the access token and [php-google-spreadsheet-client](https://github.com/asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client) to pull in the data from a Google Spreadsheet I'm working with.  I recently got everything working on localhost, but as soon as I pushed everything to the server, [I got the error](http://hackingedu.co): . . . ([click here for actual error](http://hackingedu.co))

`Warning: include_once(./libraries/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Client.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home2/alexcory/public_html/hackingedu/application/models/model.php`

- I tried changing the path but that didn't seem to be doing anything at all.
- I checked all the dependencies of the library and I meet all of them.

I'm stuck.

- I think it might be that I'm using an `Oauth Service Account` but I honestly don't know why this wouldn't work. I read somewhere that this was the way to do it and it's worked.
- If it *is* because of that then maybe I need to be using an `Oauth Web Application`.  I tried this when first starting with the API but couldn't get it to work and stumbled across someone saying to use the `Oauth Service Account`.

**Questions:**

If I do have to use the `Oauth Web Application`, how does the `Client Secret` in the Oauth Web Application differ from the `Public Key Fingerprints` in the Oauth Service Account as shown in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOX6y.png)?

**Also**

I tried using the following code in a `DELETEme.php` file that basically just has a `die('you win');` statement in it.

```
if (file_exists('/DELETEme.php')) {
    die('/DELETEme.php');
} elseif (file_exists('../DELETEme.php')) {
    die("../DELETEme.php");
} elseif (file_exists('../../DELETEme.php')) {
    die('../../DELETEme.php');
} elseif (file_exists('../../../DELETEme.php')) {
    die('../../../DELETEme.php');
} else {
    die("losing GRRRRR");
}
```

**But I'm still getting** `losing GRRRR`.

The file structure of model.php looks like:

```
▶ home
. . . index.php
. . . DELETEme.php
. . . ▶ application
. . . . . . ▶ models
. . . . . . . . . model.php
. . . . . . ▶ controllers
. . . . . . . . . controller.php
. . . ▶ views
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run into `No such file or directory in...` errors, I usually add:

```
die(get_include_path());
```

before the include (in your case, in `.../modal.php`) to see what paths PHP is running/configured with.

More than likely, you need to let PHP know where the `libraries` directory is.  You can do so by:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/path/to/libraries');
```

or update the `include_path` directive in your php.ini config file.

Also, I see that you start your path with `./`.  This means "in the current directory".  So, does `libraries` exist in the same directory as `model.php`?  If not, then you want the path to just be `google-api-php-client/src/Google/Client.php` after you add the `/path/to/libraries` to your `include_path`.